# jq reshaping data to flat json

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am working with some json data I would like to insert in a SQL database. The data are from from Google Cloud Firestore

Input :

```
{
  "0": {
    "filed1": "xxxx",
    "field": "zzzz"

  },
  "1": {
    "field1": "xxx",
    "filed2": "zzz"
  }
}
```

Desired output, I don't want to store my field in an id body, instead I want to save my id alongside of the others fields as in a flat objet

```
{
  {
    "id": 0,
    "filed1": "xxxx",
    "field": "zzzz"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "field1": "xxx",
    "filed2": "zzz"
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) and the `*` operator:

```
jq 'to_entries | map({id: .key} * .value)' file.json
```